# Why is DefaultOverloadAttribute required in WinRT?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I recently had a WinRT class definition with methods like this:

```
public void Foo(string x){}
public void Foo(CustomClass x){}
```

The compiler threw an error though that

> The 1-parameter overloads of Earlz.FooBar must have exactly one method specified as the default overload by decorating it with Windows.Foundation.Metadata.DefaultOverloadAttribute.

What kind of implications does this attribtue have? I'm unfamiliar with how WinRT projections work, but what I'm writing will eventually be a publicly usable API. So, I want to make sure that I'm not doing something that will cause pain to people who use the API. Should I rename my `Foo` method to `FooCustom` or some such, or is using DefaultOverload on the more commonly used function the way to go?

Also, I tried looking up what this attribute does and why it's required, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.defaultoverloadattribute.aspx) was short on details as usual and just gave single sentence description "Indicates that a method is the default overload method"

I assume the primary reason for this attribute is because Javascript only supports overloading on parameter count, not parameter type. However, how would a Javascript app access the non-default WinRT methods with type overloads?

Comment: There are no implications.  Microsoft decided to require programmers define the default overload for methods.

Comment: @Ramhound but how will that work if a language doesn't support overloads?

Comment: @Ramhound For instance, in Javascript it won't be able to know which overload is attempted to be called because it only determines overloads on parameter number, not on parameter type(due to be dynamic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jesse Jiang described in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/17eee933-4b37-47de-beb6-60a5d46b1101):

> JavaScript has limited ability to differentiate overloaded methods. Therefore, you need to change the function name, or setting the Windows::Foundation::Metadata::DefaultOverloadAttribute to set the default overload function.